# How to bind an AngularJS button with ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

I am generating buttons for pagination based on the row size. My problem is when I create the button in my AngularJS function and bind it to the element the buttons display properly but the ng-click is not working.

Here is my code:

```
   var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
var url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+"index.php/";
var rowcount = <?php echo $this->session->userdata("count"); ?>;


app.controller('myctrl', function($scope, $http, $sce)
{
    $http.get(url+"exammanager/0/10").then(function(response) 
    {
        $scope.myData = response.data.exams;        
        $scope.refresh();                   
    });

    $scope.refresh = function()
    {
        $http.get(url+"exammanager/0/10").then(function(response)
        {           
            $scope.myData = response.data.exams;    
            num = Math.ceil(rowcount/10);
            counter = 0;
            var buttons = "";
            for(i = 1;i <= num; i++)
            {
                if(i != num)
                    buttons += "&nbsp<button ng-click=\"pagescopeclick(\'"+url+"index.php/exammanager/"+counter+"/10\')\" >"+i+"</button> |";
                else 
                    buttons += "&nbsp<button ng-click=\"pagescopeclick(\'"+url+"index.php/exammanager/"+counter+"/10\')\" >"+i+"</button> ";
                counter = counter + 10;         
            } 
            $scope.count = $sce.trustAsHtml(buttons);                   
        });     
    }//Refresh controller

    $scope.pagescopeclick = function(val)
    {alert();
        $http.get(val).then(function(response)
        {           
            $scope.myData = response.data.exams;                
        });     
    }//pagescopeclick move to the next page without refresh
});
```

Comment: You have to compile element before injecting into a DOM, you can use  `$compile` for the same..

Answer (score 0):

Pankaj is correct you need to use $compile. Try editing your refresh function like so, where you would use $compile just after your for loop. (Don't forget to inject $compile as a dependency)

```
$scope.refresh = function() {

  $http.get(url+"exammanager/0/10").then(function(response)
  {           
      $scope.myData = response.data.exams;    
      num = Math.ceil(rowcount/10);
      counter = 0;
      var buttons = "";
      for(i = 1;i <= num; i++)
      {
          if(i != num)
              buttons += "&nbsp<button ng-click=\"pagescopeclick(\'"+url+"index.php/exammanager/"+counter+"/10\')\" >"+i+"</button> |";
          else 
              buttons += "&nbsp<button ng-click=\"pagescopeclick(\'"+url+"index.php/exammanager/"+counter+"/10\')\" >"+i+"</button> ";
          counter = counter + 10;         
      } 
      $compile( buttons )( scope )
      $scope.count = $sce.trustAsHtml(buttons);                   
  });     

}
```

Comment: @PankajParkar It worked I replaced it as you said but the ng- click event is not

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the issue with this:

```
$scope.refresh = function()
{
    $http.get(url+"exammanager/0/10").then(function(response)
    {           
        $scope.myData = response.data.exams;    
        num = Math.ceil(rowcount/10);
        counter = 0;
        var buttons = "";
        for(i = 1;i <= num; i++)
        {
            if(i != num)
                buttons += "<button ng-click='pagescopeclick(\""+url+"exammanager/"+counter+"/10\")' >"+i+"</button>";
            else 
                buttons += "<button ng-click='pagescopeclick(\""+url+"exammanager/"+counter+"/10\")' >"+i+"</button> ";

            counter = counter + 10;         
        }              
        angular.element(document.getElementById('count')).html($compile(buttons)($scope));                  
    });     
}
```